# Link Custom Post Type Sidebar to Page/Posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I registered a new post type "sidebars" so I can create different ones whenever I like.

```
function rh_create_sidebar_post_type() {
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => __( 'Sidebars' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Sidebar' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'New Sidebar' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Sidebar' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Sidebar' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Sidebar' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Sidebar' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Sidebars' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No Sidebars Found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Sidebars found in Trash' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 
            'editor', 
            'excerpt', 
            'custom-fields', 
            'thumbnail',
            'page-attributes'
        ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'sidebar_post', $args );
} 
add_action( 'init', 'rh_create_sidebar_post_type' );
```

Then on page/post admin screens, I load a meta box with a combo box of all the sidebars I have created

```
function load_sidebar_custom_meta_box( $post )
{
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_rh_custom_sidebar', true );

    // The Query
    $args = array('post_type' => 'sidebar_post');
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<select name="rh_custom_page_sidebar" id="rh_custom_page_sidebar">';
        echo '<option value="-1">No Sidebar</option>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $selected = '';
            if ( get_the_ID() == $value )  {
                $selected = 'selected';
            }
            echo '<option value="'. get_the_ID() . '" ' .$selected .'>' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); //So custom sidebar post type doesn't overwrite main query
}
```

These two pieces work just fine. However, whenever I choose a sidebar and click save, it changes my page slug/URL to be whatever the URL is in the sidebar post type. And I can't change it back. No matter if I manually edit it at the top, and then click "OK" then "Update", it reverts back to the sidebar URL/slug.

For instance, the URL on the `.com/about-us` page I am trying to edit is now `.com/default-sidebar` and I can't change it back.

Here is my save method, not mentioning the `post_name`.

```
add_action( "save_post", "save_sidebar_post_page", 100 );
function save_sidebar_post_page( $post_ID )
{
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_ID ;
    }
    global $post;
    if( isset( $_POST['rh_custom_page_sidebar'] )) {
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_rh_custom_sidebar', $_POST['rh_custom_page_sidebar'] );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Noticed when I click "New Page" in the default Wordpress Page section, it seems to think it's my custom post_type of `sidebar_post`. Noticed when clicking on the Yoast Tab for Page Analysis, it had this error:

"No focus keyword was set for this `sidebar_post`. If you do not set a focus keyword, no score can be calculated."

So for some reason when it creates a new page, it thinks it's a sidebar post, so that must be happening when I Publish or Update, which would cause my issues with the permalink. However I am not seeing where in my code it would get these two things confused?

**UPDATE 2**

This seems to be happening after I set the custom sidebar the first time on the page. It works great and my permalink loads correctly on the front end. However, if I go back to edit the same page in the admin a second time, it looks like it loads the sidebar `post_name` in the admin in a hidden input field.

So when I update the page, that new `post_name` is getting submitted. Found the following embedded in the source after my first save. The value should be `about-us`.

```
<div class="inside">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="post_name">Slug</label><input name="post_name" type="text" size="13" id="post_name" value="test-sidebar-post">
</div>
```

What it looks like is happening is my `WP_Query` is overriding the global `$post` variable. I see what you were saying now Milo. Trying it with `get_posts`

Comment: `$post` global is a bit different on the admin side. I don't think `wp_reset_postdata` works in that context. I would try using `get_posts` instead and not touching `$post` global.

Comment: The only time I reference `global $post` is during saving, and I was only doing that during debugging. It's not actually used during this process.

Comment: you don't use it directly, but `the_post()` does. that's how the template tags get their data in the standard loop, and why you need to use `wp_reset_postdata` on the front end.

Comment: I am not using `wp_reset_postdata` on the front end; that's an `is_admin` method. I just added that recently b/c I was trying different things to try and figure why my slug was changing. It's not working though obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `WP_Query` overwriting my main query. Using `get_posts` fixed the issue.